Looses default gateway when applying quickack config on same subnet
For below interface:
iface lo inet loopback

# Network interface for LAN
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.53.81.248
        netmask 255.255.254.0

# Network interface for DATA
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.53.81.249
        netmask 255.255.254.0

ip route before quicack config:
#ip route
default via 10.53.80.1 dev eth0
10.53.80.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.53.81.248
10.53.80.0/23 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.53.81.249

quickack config:
/sbin/ip route change 10.53.80.0/23 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.53.81.249 quickack 1
ip route after quickack config:
# ip route
10.53.80.0/23 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.53.81.249 quickack 1
10.53.80.0/23 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.53.81.249

why it is happening like this not getting, please help me to get understanding for this issue and what approach i should follow to resolve this issue.
